# IIS 7.5 only shows homecontroller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have my IIS set up like this:

[image: Layout]

The default website works like it should.
But the API only loads the default page

all the other routes give me
[image: Error]

Any clue on how to fix this?
this is the WebApiConfig.cs from the api

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the sollution:

The problem was that the /api worked as root, so /api/api/videos would call the video controller.